# ParentViewController is becoming nil , dont know where and how

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I am trying to make an app and the first step is to create viewControllers and link them . I know i can do that using storyboards and sueges but i wanted to do it the old school way - by coding i.e.

It contains 4 view controllers

```
-MainViewController
-SettingsViewController 
-RulesViewController
```

The three view controllers are managed using `ContainerViewController`(4th viewController) (custom container which i wrote) . The `currentSubViewController` keeps track of the viewController currently being shown

```
@implementation ContainerViewController
{
     UIViewController * currentSubViewController;
}
```

All three viewControllers are created from .nib

- Main Page has 2 buttons "Settings" and "Rules"
- Settings has 2 buttons "Main" and "Rules"
- Rules has 2 buttons "Main" and "Settings"

**On start up :**

currentSubViewController  is set to an instance of MainViewController and then

```
[container addChildViewController: currentSubViewController]
```

makes container the parent of currentSubViewController.

*And the main page shows up without any problems*

**After start up on pressing the "settings button"**

IBAction in MainViweController is called

```
- (IBAction)onSettings:(id)sender {
        if ([self parentViewController]) {
             [(ContainerViewController*)[self parentViewController showViewControllerWithName:@"settings"];
}
}
```

And then `showViewControllerWithName`  of `ContainerViewController`is called

```
- (void) showViewControllerWithName:(NSString*)vctype
{
    UIViewController * toVC = [ViewControllerFactory getViewControllerOfType:vctype]; // viewController factory returns the appropriate viewController i.e either MainViewController or SettingsViewController or  RulesViewController

    toVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds;
    toVC.view.autoresizingMask = containerView.autoresizingMask;

    [currentSubViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:toVC];

    [self transitionFromViewController:currentSubViewController
                  toViewController:toVC duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                      [currentSubViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                      [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

                  }];
    currentSubViewController = toVC;

// I checked here toVC has a parentViewController set to ContainerViewController
}
```

***SettingsViewController** shows up*

**On Pressing the "Main" Button on `SettingsViewController`**

IBACtion in SettingsMainController is called

```
 - (IBAction)onMain:(id)sender {
    if ([self parentViewController]) { // parentViewController is nil here
        [(ContainerViewController*)[self parentViewController] showViewControllerWithName:@"root"];

    }
 }
```

But ParentViewController is nil here and hence nothing is shown. The SettingsViewController is toVC from the function call `showViewControllerWithName` in the previous step.

Somewhere between `showViewControllerWithName()` and `OnMain()`, `parentViewController` is being set to `nil`. I checked till viewDidAppear and parentViewController is not nil until that point.

My Questions are

1. Where is `parentViewController` being set to nil?
2. To debug this issue i would want to know what other internal functions are called after `viewDidAppear`
3. Is using a factory class to create new UIViewControllers creating a problem?
4. is instance being created and instance being shown different?although I checked the memory address in the debugger its the same

I am unable to fix this. I tried a very hacky way where i keep track of the parent in the derived class even then `transitionFromViewController:` throws an exception saying both view controllers should have same parent.

I am stuck at this for almost two days now. I Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally was able to make it work . Let me concisely explain the question again

->`ContainerViewController` presents `MainViewController`  and when you check MainViewController.ParentController, it is infact `ContainerViewController`

->`ContainerViewController` transitions from `MainViewController` to `SettingsViewController` using the following function

```
  (void) showViewControllerWithName:(NSString*)vctype
  {
     UIViewController * toVC = [ViewControllerFactory getViewControllerOfType:vctype]; 
    toVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds;
    toVC.view.autoresizingMask = containerView.autoresizingMask;

    [currentSubViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:toVC];

    [self transitionFromViewController:currentSubViewController
              toViewController:toVC duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                  [currentSubViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                  [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

              }];
    currentSubViewController = toVC;


}
```

->After the transition `SettingsViewController.parentViewController` is nil

Following is the fix :

```
           animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                  [currentSubViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                  [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

              }];

    currentSubViewController = toVC;
```

is changed to

```
           animations:^{} completion:^(BOOL finished){

              }];
    [currentSubViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    [toVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    currentSubViewController = toVC;
```

And now `SettingsViewController` has a parent.

Well, If anyone could explain what exactly is going on then it would be great.

Comment: Because you might be accessing/checking the parent while the completion block of the animation is not yet done.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to ring in here. I had a parent/child layout setup with storyboard which was working great until one day....

It turned out I wrote a utility method named:
-(UIViewController*)addChildViewController:(UIViewController*)chidViewController

It turns out I wasn't very creative with my method name and I overwrote a UIViewController method. All I had to do was rename it and I was back in business. This took me a long time to track down!